# How can I alias a static template method?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have the following class:

```
struct A
{
    template<typename T1, typename T2>
    static double constexpr getPercentage(const T1 t1, const T2 t2)
    {
        return 100.0 * static_cast<double>(t1) / static_cast<double>(t2);
    }
};
```

I have aliased and use `A::getPercentage` for `B` as follows:

```
struct B
{
    template<typename T1, typename T2>
    using getPercentage = decltype(A::getPercentage<T1, T2>);

    void f()
    {
        const double d = getPercentage(1.0, 2.0); //ERROR: Cannot refer to class template 'getPercentage' without a template argument list
    }
};
```

What is wrong with this? How can I avoid this error?

Comment: Your declaration of `B::getPercentage` makes it a *type* and not a function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`using` is a type alias](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias). `getPercentage` is not a type, it is a function. You cannot alias functions.

Form what your intent looks like, a forwarding function would be more appropriate.

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
double constexpr getPercentage(T1&& t1, T2&& t2)
{
    return A::getPercentage(std::forward<T1>(t1), std::forward<T2>(t2));
}
```

For a full listing;

```
struct A
{
    template<typename T1, typename T2>
    static double constexpr getPercentage(const T1 t1, const T2 t2)
    {
        return 100.0 * static_cast<double>(t1) / static_cast<double>(t2);
    }
};

struct B
{
    template <typename T1, typename T2>
    static constexpr double getPercentage(T1&& t1, T2&& t2)
    {
        return A::getPercentage(std::forward<T1>(t1), std::forward<T2>(t2));
    }

    void f()
    {
        const double d = getPercentage(1.0, 2.0);
    }
};
```

Comment: Should I do this: `template<typename T1, typename T2> static auto getPercentage = SimulatorOutcomeStorage::getPercentage<T1, T2>;` ?

Comment: No, that declares a variable `getPercentage`. If you wanted to explore the variable option, you could look to `std::function`.

Comment: @Vahagn You wouldn't get type deduction if you used that.

Answer (score 2):

You can't alias functions. Your `getPercentage` alias is an alias for the *type* of `A::getPercentage`.

Instead of aliasing `A::getPercentage`, you could add a forwarding function:

```
struct B
{
    //forwarding function
    template<typename T1, typename T2>
    static double constexpr getPercentage(const T1 t1, const T2 t2) 
    {
        return A::getPercentage(t1,t2);    
    }

    void f()
    {
        //calls B::getPercentage, which calls A::getPercentage
        const double d = getPercentage(1.0, 2.0); 
    }
};
```

Comment: No way to use the function pointer directly without defining a new function and adding some overhead in performance, plus polluting the code?

Comment: @Vahagn I doubt there'll be any performance overhead here, `B::getPercentage` will almost certainly be optimized out. You're probably hoping for template function using declarations, but it is unlikely they'll get put in the language (see [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_closed.html#109)).